# Retrieve Data From Shared Preference

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

On My Equal Button in a calculator I designed I store data into share preference for history backup like this

```
historyList.add(calcInput.getText().toString()+"  =  "+calcOutput.getText().toString());

stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : historyList){

        stringBuilder.append(s);
        stringBuilder.append(",");

}

editor.putString("hist", stringBuilder.toString());
editor.apply();
```

And Retrives Data like that with a button click

```
historyString = setting.getString("hist", null);
historyAdaptorArray = historyString.split(",");
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, historyAdaptorArray);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now my problem is that every time I load app previous history data gone when new value is added to sharedpreference.
What should I do to have data always available until I clear?

Comment: your backing things up in Shared Pref? Not a good idea. If the user reinstalls the app, the restarts the cache, everything is gone. Use Firebase or Parse-Server

Comment: no i dont wanna store forever. can u please guide me regarding the issue listed above? :)

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: Can you post the code that loads and saves your SharedPreference history data?

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial this is a better tutorial that shows saving (put) and getting it (get)

Comment: Save code like that 
editor.putString("hist", stringBuilder.toString());
        editor.apply();
Load Code Like that
historyString = setting.getString("hist", null);
            historyAdaptorArray = historyString.split(",");

Comment: i want to append data to my shared preference instead of creating new shared preference every time i open app. :)

Comment: I'm downvoting for lack of research effort because you didn't read the tag descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the data the use it like this.

```
editor.putString("hist", setting.getString("hist", null)+   
stringBuilder.toString());
editor.apply();
```

This will get the previous sharedPreference value and append on it the new string builder values.

Hope it helps :)